# Get name of a repository var in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, repository

I have a function that checks if a user has access to a repository.

```
public function getACL($repository, $granted){

    if (false === $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted($granted, $repository)) {

        $this->get('log')->writeLog('Access denied.', __LINE__, 3);
        return new JsonResponse(array(
            'result' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Not allowed'
        ));
    }

    return true;
}
```

**The Call**

```
/* Get Client */
$client = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Client')->find($request->get('clientId'));

/* Get ACL */
$this->get('global_functions')->getACL($client, 'VIEW');
```

**What I'd like to get**

I would like to see the name of the repository the user has been denied to, like this:

```
$this->get('log')->writeLog('Access denied to $REPOSITORYNAME.', __LINE__, 3);
```

in this case `$REPOSITORYNAME` should be `AppBundle:Client` or even only `Client`

Is that at all possible?
is there a way t

Comment: First of all, you're not dealing with repository here, but it's an instance of `Client` (entity) retrieved from repository. Also check `get_class()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be so

```
$this->get('log')->writeLog('Access denied to '.get_class($repository).'.', __LINE__, 3);
```

or

```
$class = get_class($repository);
$this->get('log')->writeLog('Access denied to '.substr($class, strrpos($class, '\\') + 1).'.', __LINE__, 3);
```

or I didn't understand question